# iOS Modal Segue causing Out of Bounds crash

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view with a Sign In button which is placed programatically on the top right corner on viewWillAppear:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign In", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(signIn))
```

The same view controller features the following method:

```
@objc func signIn() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginNewSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

The idea is for the Sign In button to show a modal sign in screen. In storyboard I connected the first screen's view with the Sign in view using a Present Modally segue and gave it the identifier "loginNewSegue".

However, when I run the app and I click on the Sign In button, the app crashes and I get the following:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'
```

While I don't tap on the Sign In button, everything works fine.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

UPDATE: If I try the following:

```
@objc func signIn() {
    print("HERE1")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginNewSegue", sender: nil)
    print("HERE2")
}
```

The first print appears in the console. The crash happens before the second print.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be segue issue. What else you have in code? you need to be more clear.

Comment: These are literally all the lines I added. If I don't click on the Sign In button, everything else works normally.

Comment: and what if you comment that line inside function?

Comment: Which line? the print statements weren't there originally. I added them after I started getting the crash.

Comment: Do you have anything related to arrays in controller you are presenting?

Comment: It's a collection view so yes. But like I said, everything loads fine and works with no issues (I can even navigate to other screens) until I tap the sign in button. This fires performSegue and that is where the app crashes.

Comment: Found the error. The destination screen had a string which has colored characters. I had deleted one character without updating the part of the code which counted them. Thanks for your help!